# Find dropped statement according to start time and end time in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to big dataframe like dummy samples below, df1 is before adjustment process and df2 is after adjustment. Logic says all statements in df1 has to preserved and be in df2. df2 can have some extra new statements.

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
      ~DATE,           ~ID, ~Unit_id, ~Start_time, ~End_time,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,      73400L,    73859L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     155900L,   160059L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     160700L,   163459L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     163500L,   163759L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     172500L,   172759L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,      64400L,    73359L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     160100L,   160659L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     170800L,   171059L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     174500L,   174559L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     151L,     172800L,   173059L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     151L,     173100L,   174459L
  )
```

and

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
      ~DATE,           ~ID, ~Unit_id, ~Start_time, ~End_time,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,      73400L,    73859L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     155900L,   160059L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     160700L,   163459L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     163500L,   163759L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,      64400L,    73359L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     142L,     160100L,   160659L,
  20221028L, "21101732-aa",     160L,     180100L,   183659L,
  )
```

In my case I noticed that several original statements have dropped in the process. In another word these statements are available in df1 but not available in df2. How can I find dropped statement per date, ID, unit_id and start_time and end_time. My desired output should be similar to this:

```
DATE         ID        Unit_id   Start_time End_time
20221028    21101732-aa  142        172500  172759
20221028    21101732-aa  142        170800  171059
20221028    21101732-aa  142        174500  174559
20221028    21101732-aa  151        172800  173059
20221028    21101732-aa  151        173100  174459
```

Comment: Have you tried  `anti_join()` function from the dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

```
anti_join(df1, df2)
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
      DATE ID          Unit_id Start_time End_time
     <int> <chr>         <int>      <int>    <int>
1 20221028 21101732-aa     142     172500   172759
2 20221028 21101732-aa     142     170800   171059
3 20221028 21101732-aa     142     174500   174559
4 20221028 21101732-aa     151     172800   173059
5 20221028 21101732-aa     151     173100   174459
```